# What's the best way to (de)serialize a Java object to file

Tags: java, serialization

I'd like to save a Java object to file (for unit testing later on). I have tried JSON but since I don't own the classes to the objects I'm serializing, deserialization becomes more effort than it is worth. (The getters and setters to the existing classes are overloaded with different types and Jackson cannot figure out how to deserialize the object)

Now I'm exploring other avenues (i.e. serializing to binary or some other format). I'm wondering if there is anything out there that can dump a Java object to binary/file so that deserialization is trivial. I understand you can do this with the `Serializable` interface, but again I don't own these classes which don't implement this interface so they cannot be modified.

Comment: If they don't implement `Serializable` then they were not intended to be serialized.  I would ask the developers of the library what they suggest you do or whether you should be doing something else.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could also use [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html) which does not depents on classes having implemented `Serializable` interface.

Comment: +1 I was about to post this answer. I have good experience with XStream: it's fast, gives clean XML, works around issues with final fields, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try XStream to see if it can do what Jackson cannot :)

Answer (score 0):

if they implement `Serializable` you do not need to own them (nor modify them), you can just write them to file using an `ObjectOutputStream` and read them back in with a `ObjectInputStream`

Assuming the classes have proper getters and setters you should have no issue doing this

Comment: This is the problem: they don't implement Serializable. The getters and setters are ambiguous and therefore Jackson has a hard time figuring out how to deserialize the object.

Comment: do you strictly need a JSON output type?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Kryo](http://code.google.com/p/kryo/). Benchmarks ([here](http://code.google.com/p/kryo/wiki/V1Benchmarks) and [here](http://code.google.com/p/thrift-protobuf-compare/wiki/Benchmarking)) say it is one of the fastest to serialize/deserialize and uses less space too. It also doesn't need `Serializable` to be implemented. That said, I have never used it personally.